# package does not exist android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, package

I get the following error when trying to execute the following line of code.

```
import com.example.albert.helper.SessionManager;
```

Error:(15, 33) error: package com.example.albert.helper does not exist

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

[image]

Comment: And you have a SessionManager class in this package ?

Comment: yea I do, its a normally declared java class. I'll add the screenshot above

Comment: Is the helper directory its own project? If so, you need to add it to your build dependency